# Error 1064 (42000): Unknown column

Tags: mysql-error-1064

I am trying to run the following code:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS location (
locationId int(10) NOT NULL,
locationName varchar(25) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`locationId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

I get an error running the code below:

INSERT INTO `location` (`locationId`, `locationName`) VALUES
(1, `Millwall Park-London`),
(2, `Isle of Dogs`),
(3, `Windsor Castle-Grounds`),
(4, `Orford Ness-Suffolk`),
(5, `Rancid Attic Studio`),
(6, `St James Park-London`);

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes:

INSERT INTO location (locationId, locationName) VALUES (1, "Millwall Park-London"), (2, "Isle of Dogs"), (3, "Windsor Castle-Grounds"), (4, "Orford Ness-Suffolk"), (5, "Rancid Attic Studio"), (6, "St James Park-London");

Hope this solves the problem.